# Upload image to server from Java

Tags: java, php

Follow a small Java code to select an image from a folder. What I would like is to know how to upload it to a server, I have always uploaded images from javascript or jquery or php too. Use a AngularJS frameworks and also to upload images Ionic from mobile devices to my server, I am now working directly in Java and have some doubts. On issues of time, I would like to know how is the best way to upload an image, `bits or base64`? And if they could help me with this conversion would appreciate. I'm new to Java and I'm just practicing. Regards!

My code :

```
public class UI extends JFrame {
JButton buttonBrowse;
JButton buttonUpload;
JLabel label;

public UI(){
    super("Set Picture Into A JLabel Using JFileChooser In Java");
    buttonBrowse = new JButton("Browse");
    buttonUpload = new JButton("Upload");
    buttonBrowse.setBounds(300,300,100,40);
    buttonUpload.setBounds(400, 300, 100, 40);
    label = new JLabel();
    label.setBounds(10,10,670,250);
    add(buttonBrowse);
    add(buttonUpload);
    add(label);

    buttonBrowse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

          JFileChooser file = new JFileChooser();
          file.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
          //filter the files
          FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.Images", "jpg","gif","png");
          file.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
          int result = file.showSaveDialog(null);
           //if the user click on save in Jfilechooser
          if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
              File selectedFile = file.getSelectedFile();
              String path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
              System.out.println(path);
              label.setIcon(ResizeImage(path));
          }
           //if the user click on save in Jfilechooser
          else if(result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION){
              System.out.println("No File Select");
          }
        }
    });

    buttonUpload.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        }
    });



    setLayout(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setSize(700,400);
    setVisible(true);
    }

     // Methode to resize imageIcon with the same size of a Jlabel
    public ImageIcon ResizeImage(String ImagePath)
    {
        ImageIcon MyImage = new ImageIcon(ImagePath);
        Image img = MyImage.getImage();
        Image newImg = img.getScaledInstance(label.getWidth(), label.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(newImg);
        return image;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new UI();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php upload file function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650262/php-upload-file-function)

Comment: I do not need PHP code, I need to verify a server from Java to PHP @wiredniko

Comment: Fair enough. Maybe update the question to make it a bit more clear.